# Passing Function Down [React]

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to pass down a function called `handleDeleteToDoItem` from the parent `ToDoContainer` to the child `ToDoListOfItems`.

This is done with `<ToDoListOfItems toDoItems={this.state.toDoItems} deleteToDoItem={this.handleDeleteToDoItem} />`

However, I'm getting an error that the function is never received by the child class when I reference it with `this.props.deleteToDoItem` when I'm rendering `ToDoItems` inside of `ToDoListOfItems`

All of the other states which I've passed down from `ToDoContainer` are being recognized, except for `deleteToDoItem` and I'm at a loss of what I've done wrong here. My IDE (Webstorm) is telling me the variable is unresolved.

Is there a different way I should be passing down functions from parent components to child components?

Thanks,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class ToDoContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            toDoItems: [],
            toDoWhat: ""
        };
       ...

        this.handleDeleteToDoItem = this.handleDeleteToDoItem.bind(this);

    }


    handleDeleteToDoItem(uniqueID) {

        let updatedItemList = this.state.toDoItems.filter(toDo => {
            return toDo.uniqueID !== uniqueID;
        });

        // Concat updated item list to blank array
        this.setState({
            toDoItems: [].concat(updatedItemList)
        })

    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <ToDoListOfItems toDoItems={this.state.toDoItems} deleteToDoItem={this.handleDeleteToDoItem} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* TODO Create a form with a submit button to add items to the todolist */}
                <form action="">
                    <div>
                        {/* Capture the value of the form input */}
                        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeToDoItem} value={this.state.toDoWhat}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.handleAddToDoItem}>Add Item to List</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// This is the container for all the indivdual items in the to-do list
class ToDoListOfItems extends Component {
    render() {

        //TODO Put in styling for the list of items

        // Use map() to iterate through each item in the to-do list, creating new elements in the list container
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.toDoItems.map(toDo => (
                    <ToDoItem key={toDo.uniqueID}
                              id={toDo.uniqueID}
                              toDoWhat={toDo.toDoWhat}
                              completed={toDo.isDone}
                              onDelete={this.props.deleteToDoItem}/>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: May be something you are missing inside your `ToDoItem` Component can I see that one too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a key name mismatch issue, because in `ToDoItem` you are passing the function by key `onDelete` not by `deleteToDoItem`:

Here:

```
<ToDoItem key={toDo.uniqueID}
    id={toDo.uniqueID}
    toDoWhat={toDo.toDoWhat}
    completed={toDo.isDone}
    onDelete={this.props.deleteToDoItem}         // here
/>
```

So inside `ToDoItem` component it will be available by `this.props.onDelete`.

**Suggestion:** To avoid the confusion use key `deleteToDoItem` at all the places.

Comment: Hey, I tired your suggestion and I'm still getting an error that `this.props.deleteToDoItem` is not being passed down. How can I further debug this?

Comment: When I update all of the keys to  `deleteToDoItem' and run the app, I get the following error `TypeError: this.props.deleteToDoItem is not a function`

Comment: @Chef1075 can you post the exact code that you are using in pastenbin and provide the link?

Comment: @Chef1075 issue is in this part: `deleteToDoItem={this.deleteToDoItem}` inside `ToDoListOfItems` component, it should be `deleteToDoItem={this.props.deleteToDoItem}`. (Notice **this.props.deleteToDoItem** because you are getting the function in props and passing that function down to TodoItem component)

Comment: Worked! Thank you for helping me with that, and helping me understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `deleteToDoItem` prop in the container class equal to an arrow function calling the `handleDeleteToDoItem` with parameters:

```
... deleteToDoItem={uniqueID => this.handleDeleteToDoItem(uniqueID)}
```

Also, using an arrow function in this way makes it so you don't need to explicitly bind the handler function. Make it into an arrow function (above) and it is automatically bound.